# Replace the post count on wp_list_categories with "Has Posts" instead of number and "No Posts" if none

Tags: categories

How can this be achived?

Replace the post count on wp_list_categories with "Has Posts" instead of number and "No Posts" if none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below in your theme's **functions.php**. It should work the way you want

```
function my_list_categories( $output, $args ) {
    $output = str_replace( '(0)', '(No Posts)', $output );
    $output = preg_replace( '/\((\d+)\)/', '(Has Posts)', $output );
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'my_list_categories', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This replaced the post number, but it also changed the post category name. I need it to only replace the "(12)" for example

Comment: I have improved the answer, please check. Now it should be fine